# Color filtering with dependencies between colors

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, nvidia-jetson

My current goal is to make a color filter (threshold maybe) that creates a mask for regions with something like the following relations:

```
B < G

G > 128

R > 1.5 * G
```

I created such an algorithm already, but it loops through every pixel of the image and manually detects if these conditions are met. Which - as you might already guessed - is rather slow.

On the previous machine (NUCi7) the resulting program could reach about 6-10 FPS, but it was run entirely on the CPU.
Now I switched to a Jetson Xavier NX to have a look at OpenCV accelerated by the GPU. Currently I am looking for a function or several ones, that can realize these conditions in a way that is efficient.

I am not trying to get the most efficient way, if that one is too complicated for a start. But I tested some [Object Tracking](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-examples/tree/master/object%20detection/image%20viewer) algorithms that worked like a charm on 40+ FPS and HD2K Images, so I hope there is a way to get this done and end up with 40+/60+ FPS as well.

Something like the [inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) function would be great, but that seems to not yet exist for GPU-OpenCV. Maybe there is a clever way to realize it with [thresholds](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html#gpu-threshold), but so far I have just found it with static values.

.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html

```
image.forEach<Pixel>
        (
            [&](Pixel &pixel, const int * position) -> void
            {
                if (pixel.z > 1.5 * pixel.y &&
                    (pixel.y > pixel.x) && 
                    pixel.y > 128){
                        pixel.z = 255;
                        pixel.y = 255;
                        pixel.x = 255;
                } else {
                        pixel.z = 0;
                        pixel.y = 0;
                        pixel.x = 0;
                }
            }
        );
```

The code is basically [this one](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-examples/blob/master/object%20detection/image%20viewer/cpp/src/main.cpp) where I want to start from. Applying the foreach loop from above.

The actual current code is this one:

```
while (viewer.isAvailable()) {
        // Grab images
        if (zed.grab(runtime_parameters) == ERROR_CODE::SUCCESS) {

            // Retrieve left image
            zed.retrieveImage(image_zed, VIEW::LEFT, MEM::GPU,new_image_size);
            cv::Mat image_ocv = slMat2cvMat(image_zed);

            // <!-- Everything here is a test to insert a custom 3D-Bounding box into the live-image
            sl::ObjectData newObject;
            sl::ObjectData refObject;
            std::cout << "\n\nNew Loop" << endl;

            // Retrieve Detected Human Bodies
            zed.retrieveObjects(objects, objectTracker_parameters_rt);

            int id = 42;
            sl::float3 newPosition = {-.1,.1,-0.5};
            sl::float3 newVelocity = {.0,.0,.0};
            
            std::vector<sl::float3> newBounding_box;
            sl::float3 pOri = {looper[0],looper[1],looper[2]};
            sl::float3 pDim = {0.25,0.25,0.25};
            sl::float3 p0 = {pOri[0]-pDim[0]/2,pOri[1]-pDim[1]/2,pOri[2]-pDim[2]/2};
            sl::float3 p1 = {pOri[0]-pDim[0]/2,pOri[1]-pDim[1]/2,pOri[2]+pDim[2]/2};
            sl::float3 p2 = {pOri[0]+pDim[0]/2,pOri[1]-pDim[1]/2,pOri[2]+pDim[2]/2};
            sl::float3 p3 = {pOri[0]+pDim[0]/2,pOri[1]-pDim[1]/2,pOri[2]-pDim[2]/2};
            sl::float3 p4 = {pOri[0]-pDim[0]/2,pOri[1]+pDim[1]/2,pOri[2]-pDim[2]/2};
            sl::float3 p5 = {pOri[0]-pDim[0]/2,pOri[1]+pDim[1]/2,pOri[2]+pDim[2]/2};
            sl::float3 p6 = {pOri[0]+pDim[0]/2,pOri[1]+pDim[1]/2,pOri[2]+pDim[2]/2};
            sl::float3 p7 = {pOri[0]+pDim[0]/2,pOri[1]+pDim[1]/2,pOri[2]-pDim[2]/2};
            std::vector<sl::uint2> newBounding_box_2d = {
                {250,30},
                {1500,30},
                {1500,500},
                {250,500}};
            newBounding_box.push_back(p0);
            newBounding_box.push_back(p1);
            newBounding_box.push_back(p2);
            newBounding_box.push_back(p3);
            newBounding_box.push_back(p4);
            newBounding_box.push_back(p5);
            newBounding_box.push_back(p6);
            newBounding_box.push_back(p7);
            sl::float3 newDimensions = {1.0,1.0,1.0};

            newObject.id = id;
            newObject.position = pOri;
            newObject.velocity = newVelocity;
            newObject.bounding_box_2d = newBounding_box_2d;
            newObject.bounding_box = newBounding_box;
            newObject.dimensions = pDim;
            objects.object_list.push_back(newObject);
            // --> End of the 3D-Bounding box insert

/*          image_ocv.forEach<Pixel>
                (
                    [&](Pixel &pixel, const int * position) -> void {
                        if (pixel.z > 1.5 * pixel.y && pixel.y > pixel.x && pixel.y > 128) {
                            pixel.z = 255; pixel.y = 255; pixel.x = 255;
                        } else {
                            pixel.z = 0; pixel.y = 0; pixel.x = 0;
                        }
                    }
                );*/
            //Update GL View
            viewer.updateView(image_zed, objects);
        }
    }
cv::Mat slMat2cvMat(Mat& input) {
    // Mapping between MAT_TYPE and CV_TYPE
    int cv_type = -1;
    switch (input.getDataType()) {
        case MAT_TYPE::F32_C1: cv_type = CV_32FC1; break;
        case MAT_TYPE::F32_C2: cv_type = CV_32FC2; break;
        case MAT_TYPE::F32_C3: cv_type = CV_32FC3; break;
        case MAT_TYPE::F32_C4: cv_type = CV_32FC4; break;
        case MAT_TYPE::U8_C1: cv_type = CV_8UC1; break;
        case MAT_TYPE::U8_C2: cv_type = CV_8UC2; break;
        case MAT_TYPE::U8_C3: cv_type = CV_8UC3; break;
        case MAT_TYPE::U8_C4: cv_type = CV_8UC4; break;
        default: break;
    }

    // Since cv::Mat data requires a uchar* pointer, we get the uchar1 pointer from sl::Mat (getPtr<T>())
    // cv::Mat and sl::Mat will share a single memory structure
    return cv::Mat(input.getHeight(), input.getWidth(), cv_type, input.getPtr<sl::uchar1>(MEM::GPU));
}
```

The code as is works, but the added `ForEach-Loop` results in an Segmentation fault.

[I asked a followup question, that might be the answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126907/change-cudagpumat-values-through-custom-cernel)

Comment: That looks like a pretty simple per pixel test; just one that might not be pre-written.  Have you looked into shader languages (cuda, glsl, sksl, etc etc)?  What level of portability do you need? (Nvidia only?)  What output do you need, and where do you need it to go?  Is the image already on the gpu?  Did you try scanline based multithreading?  How many pixels are we talking about?

Comment: Are you running in release? how much does it take? please show a [mcve] that other may copy&paste

Comment: It only needs to work on the xavier, not going to use it somewhere else. The goal is to reduce each live-video-image to the regions fulfilling these conditions, so some form of cv::Mat or sl::Mat would be great. The image is on the GPU, as per default in the StereoLabs software. Havent looked at scanline based multithreading, will do so. 3840x1080 and 2560x720.

Comment: I included a link to the code at the bottom of the question.

Comment: did you try to perform Mat operation directly instead of pixel level based comparison. It is possible that the Mat operations are accelerated and then combined together give better results than pixel level one. Eg creating a mask Mat for `G > 128`, ...

Comment: My biggest problem with trying different solutions is, that every OpenCV approach results in a Segmentation fault. I have to solve that first to evaluate further.