# Change cuda::GpuMat values through custom kernel

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am using a kernel to "loop" over a live camera stream to highlight specific color regions. These can not always be reconstructed with some `cv::threshold`s, therefor I am using a kernel.

The current kernel is as following:

```
__global__ void customkernel(unsigned char* input, unsigned char* output, int width, int height, int colorWidthStep, int outputWidthStep) {
    const int xIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const int yIndex = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((xIndex < width) && (yIndex < height)) {
        const int color_tid = yIndex * colorWidthStep + (3*xIndex);
        const int output_tid = yIndex * outputWidthStep + (3*xIndex);
        const unsigned char red   = input[color_tid+0];
        const unsigned char green = input[color_tid+1];
        const unsigned char blue  = input[color_tid+2];
        if (!(red > 100 && blue < 50 && red > 1.0*green)) {
            output[output_tid] = 255;
            output[output_tid+1] = 255; 
            output[output_tid+2] = 255;
        } else {
            output[output_tid] = 0;
            output[output_tid+1] = 0;
            output[output_tid+2] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This kernel gets called here:

```
extern "C" void myFunction(cv::cuda::GpuMat& input, cv::cuda::GpuMat& output) {
    // Calculate total number of bytes of input and output image
    const int colorBytes = input.step * input.rows;
    const int outputBytes = output.step * output.rows;

    unsigned char *d_input, *d_output;

    // Allocate device memory
    SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc<unsigned char>(&d_input,colorBytes),"CUDA Malloc Failed");
    SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc<unsigned char>(&d_output,outputBytes),"CUDA Malloc Failed");

    // Copy data from OpenCV input image to device memory
    SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(d_input,input.ptr(),colorBytes,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice),"CUDA Memcpy Host To Device Failed");

    // Specify a reasonable block size
    const dim3 block(16,16);

    // Calculate grid size to cover the whole image
    const dim3 grid((input.cols + block.x - 1)/block.x, (input.rows + block.y - 1)/block.y);

    // Launch the color conversion kernel
    custom_kernel<<<grid,block>>>(d_input,d_output,input.cols,input.rows,input.step,output.step);

    // Synchronize to check for any kernel launch errors
    SAFE_CALL(cudaDeviceSynchronize(),"Kernel Launch Failed");

    // Copy back data from destination device meory to OpenCV output image
    SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(output.ptr(),d_output,outputBytes,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost),"CUDA Memcpy Host To Device Failed");

    // Free the device memory
    SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(d_input),"CUDA Free Failed");
    SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(d_output),"CUDA Free Failed");
}
```

I included an example image that shows the result of the kernel on a red car. As you can see there are vertical red lines, even though I tried to access RGB/BGR values and set them either to zero or 255.

[image: Example Image]

I used the following as a start, but I feel like `cv::Mat` and `cv::cuda::GpuMat` do not save their values in the same way. I read about GpuMat only having a ptr to its data, and thought that it would be used with the `blockIdx`, `blockDim` parameters.
https://github.com/sshniro/opencv-samples/blob/master/cuda-bgr-grey.cpp

Specific questions:

1. What is the reason for the red lines?
2. How can I change the RGB values correctly?

I am using Cuda 10.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 on a NVidia Xavier NX.

As mentioned in the comments I changed the parameters of the `cudaMemcpy` function and deleted the `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` parts. Additionally I reminded myself, that OpenCV stores color in BGR, so I changed the (+0,+1,+2) inside the kernel.
And I loaded the red car directly via cv::imread, to exclude any previous formatting errors. Too great success, the kernel works.
[image: First revision]

Comment: [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cudamemcpy-opencv-gpumat-to-memory-of-triton-inference-server/158382) may be of interest

Comment: `cudaMemcpy` should fail or have undefined behavior because `GpuMat`'s data already resides on the GPU. You must use `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` for both `cudaMemcpy` calls.

Comment: Also, no need to allocate new memory in this case. You can just use `d_input = input.ptr();` and `d_output = output.ptr();`.

Comment: I updated the question with a first success, thank you very much for that. Now I am wondering whether I should open a new question as the problem now seems to be the correct transformation from sl::Mat to Gpu::Mat. I used this one https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-opencv/issues/60#issuecomment-416199604 but that seems to not work correctly. As the colors are still not working like with the 'imread->GpuMat'

Comment: Well, .. if you put a RGBA Image in, it will be converted to a BGRA inside OpenCV, so you do not want to use (3*xIndex) but (4*xIndex) instead.. It is working now. If you want you can post your answer as an actual post, so I can accept it. If not I will write one myself tomorrowish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [@sgarizvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231073/sgarizvi) in the comments the `cv::cuda::GpuMat` already resides in the Gpu, so I had to use `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` instead of `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice`.

It was also not necessary to allocate new memory, which was achieved deleting the `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` parts of the code above.

At last (just in this case, might be different for others) my Image input was the Zed 2 from StereoLabs, which publishes its images in **RGBA** so the order inside the memory is R -> G -> B -> A, converted to OpenCV it is B -> G -> R -> A which are 4 steps per pixel:

```
const int color_tid = yIndex * colorWidthStep + (4*xIndex);
const int output_tid = yIndex * outputWidthStep + (4*xIndex);
```

So to correctly adress each pixel you have to increase the pointer by four times the xIndex, use three times if you just have a BGR/RGB image or once if it is grayscale.