# How can I pass a cv::cuda::GpuMat to a method defined in a .cu file (and to a CUDA kernel)?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

Suppose I have a cv::cuda::GpuMat defined in a .cpp file (main.cpp):

```
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.cuh"
int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    auto instance = MyClass();
    cv::cuda::GpuMat img = cv::cuda::GpuMat(512, 512, 3);
    instance.foo(img);
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

MyClass.cuh is defined as follow:

```
#pragma once
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    __device__ void foo(cv::cuda::GpuMat& gpumat);
};
```

And MyClass.cu is defined as follow:

```
#include "MyClass.cuh"
#include <iostream>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
#include "MyClass.cuh"


MyClass::MyClass() {
}
__device__ void MyClass::foo(cv::cuda::GpuMat& gpumat) {
    // Do nothing...
}
```

My program crash, why does that happen?
My goal is to call a CUDA kernel from a method defined in a class. Is this possible? If not, why so? And how can I safely pass a cv::cuda::GpuMat to a CUDA kernel? (note that my goal here is to perform some operations to this gpumat and I want to avoid any possible copy since the gpumat.data pointer should already be pointing to GPU memory)

Comment: 1. A function marked with `__device__` cannot be called directly from host code.  2.  A function marked with `__device__` is **not** a CUDA kernel.  3.  `cv::cuda::GpuMat` is not going to be directly usable in device code.  You will need to extract relevant things like pointers to the data, shape of data, etc. and [pass those to a CUDA kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126907/change-cudagpumat-values-through-custom-kernel).

Comment: What if I define `foo` as `__host__`then? I would like to use it just as a wrapper for my actual CUDA kernel.

Comment: Ok, defining it as __host__ it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This post will adress the point of accessing GpuMat data in a kernel since your other point as been fixed by the previous comments.

Since GpuMat is C++ host code only you must transform the GpuMat into a structure with host/device functions.

In OpenCV you can use a cv::cuda::PtrStepSz.  since you create a CV_16U matrix T=unsigned short

to read or write data use the operator()(const int row, const int col).

```
__global__
void myKernel(const PtrStepSz<unsigned short> image)
{
    int row, column; 
    // convert threadId to pixel coordinates
    ...
    ushort pxValue = image(row, column);
}
```

You may find some informations on this old OpenCV Documentation ( [PtrStepSz](https://docs.huihoo.com/opencv/2.4-documentation/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html) )